# try to get group info using APIs Explorer

Tags: google-apps-script

Here we use a lot of google groups to organize, when i create a new group i have to set manually all the preferences.. very boring!!

So i'd like to write a google apps script (if possible) to do the work. I found the "Groups settings API" and to understand i'm playing in the playground;. I set uniqueId of a group (the mail address) and checked out  some fields like description, i was expecting to see the field's content somewhere, But  it always  give back  something like this:

```
Request

GET https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/xxx%40aaaaa.it?fields=description&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response

400 OK

```
cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  213
content-type:  application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 10:29:37 GMT
expires:  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 10:29:37 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

[application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml; charset=UTF-8 data]
```

Using a patch action i can change the group description but in the playground i have a response like the previous

I'm very new to this environment and missing some basic info, the questions are:
- where are the information caming back from the api?
- can Google Apps Script use the APIs?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an API provided through advanced services within Google apps script to do use group settings.  Find info on this api [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-groups-settings).
To enable it in apps script, from the script editor, open the resources menu and select Advanced Google Services.
Scroll down the the group settings api and turn it on.  You will also need to enable this api in the developers console.  To do this, open your developers console, select APIS and Auth, Apis, then search for and enable the group settings api.

You can now use the api within the script using the AdminGroupsSettings object.

For example, to get a group use the following code:

```
var groupId = 'yourGroupId@gmail.com';
var group = AdminGroupSettings.get(groupId);
```

You can modify the group as you with and apply the changes with the .update or .patch method.

Comment: It works!
I can list all group properties as i needed!

I still wondering where i can find data from APIs Explorer...

Thank you Jonathan

Comment: I am not super familiar with API explorer unfortunately so I think I've been all the help I am going to be.  You should be able to get any information that you could get from the API explorer from the API though!

Comment: Now i have a spreadsheet filled with the settings of all google groups in my domain. and a function for create and edit groups using a group as template,
But i  have noticed that only 28 settings can be get/set by this API,  is it true? And for some of the API setting (p.e. messageDisplayFont) i can not find the setting in the Group management interface. Maybe i miss something?